# Can't access data in php file sent via jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to access some data in php file sent via jquery ajax method
but I get an error of Undefined Index.

sender.php

```
$('#slot1').click(function(){
            var selectedDate = $('#selectedDate').html();
            var timeSlot = $('#timeSlot1').html();

            var hm = timeSlot.slice(0, 5);
            var seconds = ':00';
            var time = hm + seconds;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'insertBookings.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: {date: selectedDate, timeslot: time},
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
              }
            })
})
```

reciver.php

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
echo date;
?>
```

Comment: What _is_ in `$_POST` when you `var_dump()` it? Also, what is in `insertBookings.php` - you showed us `reciver.php` instead.

Comment: just before your ".ajax" call, try putting  alert(selectedDate + " " + time); and see what you're actually sending.  we're flying blind here as your html is not posted in your question.

Comment: var_dump gives String(4). and i named insertbookings.php as reciver.php .

Comment: My guess is that `date: selectedDate` isn't set ..  What does the HTML element `#selectedDate` look like?  And can you `console.log(selectedDate);` --  Just to see if it IS infact set ..

Comment: i am sending string data in both selectedDate and time.

Comment: <h5>Date: <span id='selectedDate'></span></h5> this is the tag from where i get data.

Comment: Does your network tab in your console show values being passed to `receiver.php`??

Comment: Does the request reach your php script? Can you verify by sending some data back to the client?

Comment: yes in network tab i can see my data in 'request' tab, and yes request reach the php script because there is status code = 200.

Comment: @Rudrasoni in your Request tab, what do you see as far as the data being sent to the server?

Comment: `echo date;` looks pretty wrong, or did you define that constant anywhere?

Comment: Also, are you sure you've shared the correct code? Where's the content of `insertBookings.php`?

Comment: Try `echo $date;` instead (note the $)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider testing with the following.

```
$('#slot1').click(function() {
  var selectedDate = $('#selectedDate').text().trim();
  var timeSlot = $('#timeSlot1').text().trim();
  var selectedTime = timeSlot.slice(0, 5) + ":00";
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insertBookings.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "date": selectedDate,
      "timeslot": selectedTime
    },
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log("Sending Date: " + selectedDate + ", Time: " + time);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Received: ", data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("Error:", status, error);
    }
  });
});
```

No major changes, yet I switched from `.html()` to `.text()`. The former will gather more than just the text if there is anything. Since you did not provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is a precaution to ensure you're not capturing incorrect items before sending them.

I also added some extra Ajax code to help see each part as it happens.

In your PHP, you have a syntax error too. You are missing a `$` before `date`.

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: yes i missed $ before date;